# Luatex does not compile with Junicode

Tags: fonts, luatex, compiling

With

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont{Junicode}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

my compiler (0.80.0) stops at

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
```

It finishes with another font, and also with Junicode with a very short text, such as `hello, world`. I just `tlmgr update --all`ed.

Comment: And (just to test) with XeTeX?

Comment: no prob. w. xetex

Comment: Hmm, confirmed: you're right about both the short and long texts....

Comment: With context it works too so you should probably make a bug report at the luaotfload site https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues.

Comment: https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/322

Comment: It works for me if I use `\usepackage[tuenc]{fontspec}` (with a very recent fontspec)

Comment: For me that just causes the halt to occur at a different point.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, could it have to do with the luatex version? how did you get 0.88?

Comment: @Lawrence yes sorry thought it was the fontenc but I suspect that it is just that the context derived lua font loader has "got ahead of itself" and relies on some luatex 0.8x features (I compile the luatex binary from source) sorry I can't easily revert back to 0.80 to debug I'll leave that to Will, similar issues did show up during luaotfload testing and some parts were held back, perhaps they missed something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a problem with Junicode and, with the available information, it is not clear whether it depends on `luaotfload` or not.

The following example hangs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Junicode}

\begin{document}

elleat

\end{document}
```

On the other hand

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Renderer=Basic]{Junicode}

\begin{document}

elleat

\end{document}
```

compiles.

See https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/322 for a source of the example.

### Update

The issue seems to have been solved with `luaotfload` version 2016-02-12 (revision 39699 in TeX Live).

Comment: As to Feb. 26, 2017, the problem persists.

Comment: @NVaughan Works for me.